# HTML element is inserted into DOM at multiple strange points

Tags: html, css, dom

I have the following code within my HTML, which seems simple enough:

```
<div>
    <a" class="test">Test</span>
</div>
```

But when I go to render it, the `a` element gets replicated all over the page. Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers use HTML5 parsing algorithm which has special rules for misnested tags: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser. Different behavior with inline display, I guess, is due to different white space processing models for inline and block formatting contexts, resulting in different text content that appears in the implicit elements created by this algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using your HTML tags correctly.

```
<div>
    <a class="test">Test</a>
</div>
```

The code above should render correctly. You must close your anchor tags with < /a> and not a < /span> tag.

(Pardon the space, it wouldn't render the HTML without it.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue earlier and found a number of things after diving deeper into it and I thought it was worth sharing my findings. I was able to replicate the issue with this simple code:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <a class="test">Test</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="three>
    <div id="four">
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will render with not one, not two, but three instances of the `a` element, without the content, but with css classes intact.(in one after two, and wrapping three and four).

But wait, it gets weirder:

- If you replace the ending `span` tag with `</div>` the link is still
  replicated, but now only twice, with the link wrapping three and four no longer present.
- If you add `style="display:inline;"` to the version with an ending `</div>` the behaviour will be the same as with an ending span. Even stranger once you realize that `a` is already an inline element.
- The results are consistent across browsers, meaning it is most likely not just a quirk of one engine, but something inherent to HTML. (Tried on webkit and Gecko browsers, but haven't tried Trident yet).

Hope you find this interesting/useful. Certainly threw me for a loop the first time I saw it.

Comment: it's not weird at all.  you didn't close your `a` tag, so the browser is just guessing at what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @miah if the browser guessed at it, then I agree this wouldn't be that strange, but it performs identically across browsers meaning that this is actually a part of the html specification and could potentially be used as an obfuscated utility. Additionally, the thought that assigning an inline style to an inline element could change how it is rendered is deeply strange within a standard or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: @miah for sake of correctness, rendering engines do not guess, they deduce/parse based off a set of rules. though, i agree that this a pretty isolated question and likely won't prove useful to others — as this is a very unique scenario ...